# Can a ficus tree survive a fan?

Tags: tree-care

I keep reading that ficus trees can't handle a draft. I have a 7 foot ficus tree I just bought for my bedroom, and I run a fan all night every night, so there's a pretty permanent draft running through my room from the fan.

Will my ficus die? :(

Answer (score 1):

It should be completely OK, if the temperature is above 10C. 
Ficus trees grow outside in warm climate without any issues with wind, so the information you met must be about colder climate problem with cold draft from window in winter (yes, it can harm many pot plants).

Also, if your fan is a heater, don’t direct it onto the plant obviously.